# C++ class map object

Tags: c++

I'm generating a random `sessionId` in my API. For one `sessionId` I need to save ate same time the `userId` (to the user to which the `sessionId` belongs) and the user type (for example, admin, owner etc).

This is my hashmap:

```
std::map<std::string, SessionData*> sessionMap;
```

And this is my `SessionData` class:

```
class SessionData
{
public:
    SessionData(std::string pUserId, std::string pUserType)
    {
        userId = pUserId;
        userType = pUserType;
    }

    ~SessionData()
    {
    }

    std::string userId;
    std::string userType;
};
```

Now I don't find any solution for my problem. How to save in map to one `sessionId` the `userId` and `userType`? I have the `char sessionId[80]` that already have the `sessionId` generate by my algorithm (The algorithm is not important for the situation). I'm new in c++ but I think that is something like that:

```
sessionMap[sessionId].insert();
```

But I don't know how to insert the `userId` and `userType`, because my map is key <-> Object.. The key is `sessionId` and the object is my class `SessionData` that have the `userId` and `userType`.

EDIT 1:

My typedef struct to map:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, SessionData*> sessionMap_map_t;
sessionMap_map_t sessionMap;
```

The new insert data in map (with current time):

```
sessionMap.insert(std::make_pair(sessionId,new SessionData(userId,userType,currentTime)));
```

My map iteration (i need to have access for each iteration to currentTime inside while loop

```
 sessionMap_map_t::iterator itSessionMap = sessionMap.begin();
    while(itSessionMap != sessionMap.end())
    {
        //TODO: Get currentTime

    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your terminology is a little off. The [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) class is *not* a "hashmap". It's usually implemented using trees. [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) *is* a "hashmap".

Comment: Thanks. I'm new in c++ so some terminology is still unclear to me. I already corrected to map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SessionData *sessionData;
sessionMap.insert(std::make_pair(sessionId, sessionData));
```

---

Use iterater to traverse map:

```
for (auto itr = sessionMap.begin(); itr != sessionMap.end() ++itr) {
    std::string sessionId = itr->first();
    SessionData *sessionData = itr->second();

    // do something with userId and userType

    // to get current time
    std::string currentTime = sessionData->currentTime;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment and the code. Its not possible to use the class like i post? In your example you dont assign any value to userId and userType before, but you need right?

Comment: @Pik93 Yes, this is just showing the syntax. You should initialize `sessionData` before using it.

Comment: Yes, i understand now :)

Comment: I have other question (if you can help me, you can edit your answer).

How to iterate the map and find one sessionId and after check if the userId corresponds to the sessionId?

Comment: @Pik93 You can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it solves your problem. :-)

Comment: HI again. Imagine now my SessionData have 3 fields (userId, userType, createTime)

My sessionIds have validation (for example 30minutes) and every second i run a function. This function need to iterate all map and check the all createTimes for all sessionIds. If some createTime is bigger than 30minutes i need to delete this sessionId. My doubt is: how to iterate all map, get the createTime (to check the current date i know how to do) and delete the sessionId. If i have for example 5 sessionIds with createTime bigger than 30minutes i need to delete all during iteration. You understand? :)

Comment: @Pik93 There is error in my previous post. `itr->second` should be `SessionData *`. You can access new added `createTime` using it.

Comment: I saw...Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class SessionData
{

public:
    SessionData(std::string pUserId, std::string pUserType)
    {
        userId = pUserId;
        userType = pUserType;
    }

    ~SessionData()
    {
    }

    std::string userId;
    std::string userType;

};

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, SessionData*> sessionMap;  
  **sessionMap.insert(std::make_pair("Test_Session_12345",new SessionData("1234","Test")));**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not totally wrong.
Let's assume...

```
std::string pUserId = "MyFirstUser";
std::string pUserType = "testType";
```

...then insert it like as follows...

```
// A short method to insert a new entry...
sessionMap[pUserId] = new SessionData(pUserId, pUserType);
// using operator[] is a more elegant alternative to calling insert(...value_type(...))
```

...now it's a valid entry in your sessionMap, mapping pUserId 'unique' to an instance of SessionData.
But be aware that SessionData instances are

1. referenced via weak pointers. Beware of potential memory-leaks. Erasing entries or clearing the map doesn't delete the instances!
2. changing the member 'userId' in one of the instances doesn't implicitly change key mapping to the instance.

For those who are complaining that I did not check the entry before inserting it check following 2nd example...

```
// A more "verifying" method to insert a second entry...
pUserId = "MySecondUser";
std::map<std::string, SessionData*>::const_iterator itEntry = sessionMap.find(pUserId);
if (sessionMap.end() == itEntry)
{   // Either "old"-style...
    // sessionMap.insert(std::map<std::string, SessionData*>::value_type(pUserId, new SessionData(pUserId, pUserType));
    // ...or again elegant style...
    sessionMap[pUserId] = new SessionData(pUserId, pUserType);
}
else
{   // Example error handling in case of non-unique keys...
    throw string("error: Entry '") + pUserId + string("' is not unique");
}
```

Changing the key of an already inserted entry doesn't change the order of elements in the map.
Even if you use std::set<> or any other trick will not change this as the sort-logic of the derived binary tree is not re-invoked in case of changes to the entry members.

In case you want to find your createTime and delete it in case of exceeding 30minutes I propose following...

```
// I assume you have/implement a class 'MyTimeClass' and a static function initializing it with the current time...
MyTimeClass currenTime = MyTimeClass::currentTime();
// Let's define an intermediate not-expiring-time...
MyTimeClass oldestNotExpiringTime = currentTime - MyTimeClass(30min); // 30min is pseudo code and shall be replaced by the parameters defining the 30 minutes of expiration, however your MyTimeClass is defined
// Now, let's iterate all entries in the map using the non-const iterator (to be able to modify the map by deleting entries)...
for ( std::map<std::string, SessionData*>::iterator itEntry = sessionMap.begin(); sessionMap.end() != itEntry; /* don't ++itEntry to avoid conflicts with erase() */ )
{   // I assume you have a member 'createTime' of type 'MyTimeClass'...
    MyTimeClass createTime = itEntry->second.createTime;
    // ...and I assume it implements an operator<() to compare times...
    if (createTime < oldestNotExpiringTime)
    {   // this means the createTime is older than the oldest accepted time -> delete it but first copy the iterator to be able to resume iteration after deletion...
        std::map<std::string, SessionData*>::iterator itToDelete = itEntry;
        // Iterate the loop-iterator before deleting the entry to avoid access violations (aka SEGFAULT)...
        ++itEntry;
        // Now delete the entry...
        sessionMap.erase(itToDelete);
    }
    else
    {   // No reason to delete -> iterate regularily...
        ++itEntry;
    }
}
```

It's very important that you iterate to the next position before deleting the entry because the "old" iterator is kind of a pointer to the entry and will be deleted as well. Iterating the deleted iterator results usually in an access violaton (memory exception, SEGFAULT). This is why I make this exception if/else.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. I have another question:

Comment: Imagine now my SessionData have 3 fields (userId, userType, createTime) My sessionIds have validation (for example 30minutes) and every second i run a function. This function need to iterate all map and check the all createTimes for all sessionIds. If some createTime is bigger than 30minutes i need to delete this sessionId. My doubt is: how to iterate all map, get the createTime (to check the current date i know how to do) and delete the sessionId. If i have for example 5 sessionIds with createTime bigger than 30minutes i need to delete all during iteration. Check my EDIT 1 to see my code pls